# Ionic 3 install locally created plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have created a custom Cordova plugin locally using Cordova jar and Android studio according to my need.

Previously, I can install it easily on Cordova or Ionic (for older version) application.

Procedure I have done to install plugin:

1. **ionic cordova plugin add plugin < my custom plugin path >**
2. **npm install --save @ionic-native/< my_custom_plugin_path >**

For older version using step 1 only.

But I am unable to install it in ionic 3 application. Procedure step 2 creates file configuration related issues. And it's not giving proper error for this step.

Comment: I dont think ionic native will have a wrapper for your custom plugin..

Comment: @SurajRao,But I can see first command execute successfully and place data to its respective position. Mainly 2 step creates consfigurtion related issue.

Comment: Yes.. that is the step I am talking about.. ionic-native is a set of wrappers for existing cordova plugins inorder to inject as provider and use in app maintained by ionic. Unless you wrote a wrapper also for it, step 2 will not work. You need to use the plugin directly

Comment: as given in the answer.. depends on your global object name

Comment: @SurajRao,  how I can write wrapper for it? Have you know about it.

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/tree/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins maybe this will help.. Havent done this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should tell us what doesn't work? To implement a custom cordova plugin you have to do it that way:

```
(<any>window).plugins.YourPlugin.YourFunction...
```

Comment: what if you try it without the native? shouldn't be needed. npm install --save < my_custom_plugin_path >. Afterwards try to access it with my command above

Comment: I have tried with the above command.But still its not getting access to Plugin